# How does implementing servers with different languages work in discord.js API?

Tags: discord.js

Im learning about discord.js coding and want to support having servers where there is a dedicated  server for each of a few languages.

I know once a bot gets huge, you can have thousands of servers. My questions are:

1. Does each server have an auto assigned region code, or can I pick the region?
2. How would I set up the code/sharding to have support for a user having the ability to enter a server thats language is local to the users language?
3. How does discord servers work? Once you reach 10k+, does the user see all those servers in a list, or do they just join 1 room but the 10k servers is really just discord's abstraction for how they split it up in the backend?

How do servers grow for a bot? Does the count specify how many times a person has add a bot to a unique server? I assumed that the server you created for the bot is the 1 place everyone has to join to use the bot because it has all the role configuration and patron bot you set up, but that would mean its just 1 server, yet people have 2.5k+ (to use sharding too). Or does a server count mean the owner has manually created that many servers and set up the same configuration on each of them?

Thanks